# How to use the pipe command to open a directory after find?

Tags: find, pipe

Is there a way to opend found directories (via `find`) all in one command?

One of the things I tried to study several times and never been able to really get, is the effective use of pipe: is it maybe useful for this?

I tried things like:

```
find . -type d -name ".dir-name" | open
```

but it doesn't work. `open` is the OSX command to open a file in the associated application (Finder for directories).

Comment: What do you mean by open? Open it in a file browser? Or change the working directory to it?

Comment: Hi! I mean open the directory with finder

Comment: The reason why the pipe doesn't make sense here is because the pipe will send the output of `find` to the input of `open`, but you would have give it to open as a command line argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-exec`:

```
find . -type d -name ".dir-name" -exec open {} \;
```

Comment: That's nice. But is `open` an actual command?

Comment: According to some doc I found on the web, `open` is the command on OsX which opens a directory with `finder`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: Yes, I often use open [dir/file path] on osx. Thank you JPG. I often see that "{}" and "/" after -exec and similar: what does it mean?

Comment: `find . -type d -name "GECO*" -exec open {} \;` works! but with doesn't it work without "\"? What does it mean? Also, another very similar way: `find . -type d -name "GECO*" -exec open {} +` without "\" and semicolon: should open every match.

Comment: See [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for details. `{}` is replaced by the name of the file found; the `;` is the end of the command and must be escaped. If you replace it with `+`, the command is called with all the found files passed at the same time; some programs support it, others not.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to use a pipe this should work:

```
find . -type d -name ".dir-name" | xargs open
```

I highly suggest using `-exec` instead, but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use OSX, but try this:

```
for dirname in `find . -type d -name ".dir-name"`; do open ${dirname}; done;
```